# Vagrant Laravel new project set up

Tags: macos, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

I am now ready to start a new project with Laravel using Vagrant. My initial project worked fine but I can't seem to get the new project to show in the browser with its unique name loginauth.app.

My very first app was called PaulsApp and if I typed paulsapp.app in the browser the laravel started page showed fine.

I followed the instructions to create a new project using composer create project in my VM in the same directory as my first app. I can see this in both the local and on the VM.

Next I updated the homestead.yaml file to include the new sitemap and run vagrant provision to let the VM know of the updates.

I believe I must be overlooking something as my .yaml file has the map as homestead.app but that does not work only paulsapp.app which is in my etc/hosts file.

Please could somebody explain how the .yaml file and the hosts file are interacting. If I completely remove the mapping to PaulsApp in the yaml file, paulsapp.app in the browser still shows up the correct page.. as such I am a tad confused. I thought one simply added a mapping to the yaml and then could access that mapping through the browser. I want to type loginauth.app in the browser and have it point to the index file in the public directory of /home/vagrant/code/loginauth/ thanks.

homestead.yaml

```
    ---
    ip: "192.168.10.10"
    memory: 2048
    cpus: 1
    provider: virtualbox

    authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    keys:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

    folders:
        - map: ~/code
          to: /home/vagrant/code

    sites:
        - map: homestead.app
          to: /home/vagrant/code/PaulsApp/public
        - map: loginauth.app
          to: /home/vagrant/code/loginauth/public

    databases:
        - homestead

    variables:
        - key: APP_ENV
          value: local
```

etc/hosts

```
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost
    192.168.10.10   Paulsapp.app
    #127.0.0.1      PaulsApp.dev
```

Comment: What happens if you add the extra site to your hosts file?  `192.168.10.10   loginauth.app`

Comment: it just searches google for loginauth.app.. Thx

Answer (score 0):

OK so thanks to some help from the guys over at #laravel irc channel..

I needed to add the correct line to the hosts file. I tried 192.168.10.10 loginauth.app but got no joy so I used 127.0.0.1 loginauth.app.

Then the key was to vagrant halt the VM, Vagrant UP it again then vagrant provision it so the VM could see the changes.

Now loginauth.app:8000/ brings up the page I was hoping for...